# Powered off w/out shutdown now getting file system warnings

Tags: filesystem

Pi lost power now I get file system warnings at boot.

Comment: Without any more information noone can help you. What are exactly the warnings you get ? Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Thanks ashbay for interest in my issue,  during boot I get a scrolling screen of text (normal I assume,  new to Pi) one of the lines has FAIL and says run fsck.  I open terminal session and typed in sudo touch /forcefsck  Clearly I'm missing something as I get unknown command or similar.

Comment: Sounds like the SD card is corrupt. Always backup your images and think about using a USB drive for your file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're on Raspbian. Clearly, you should avoid power off your Pi without shutdown. You should always use the command :

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

If you power off the Pi without shutdown and the Pi was doing something with the filesystem while your turned off the pi it can cause several and unknown crashes.

As the system tell you you can try to check for the file system integrity following these steps :

1) Boot

2) Since it's asking your to start a fsck type :

```
fdisk -l
```

3) Then

```
fsck.ext3 -y /dev/...
```

4) Answer the questions the program ask you.

In my opinion your FileSystem is damaged/corrupted but **I'm not a pro linux user, wait for some other opinion maybe.** If this is really the case the only solution I know (maybe there are some other I don't know) is to reinstall your OS...

Hope it will help you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info.  NOOB to linux so everything is new.  Learning something new every day...